# Git not updated

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, git

I have problem with the installation of a program. I've googled the error and it says that I need to update git.

My git version says I'm on v2.11.0. and git website says that v2.18.0 is the newest one https://git-scm.com/. I've tried with `sudo apt install git` but it says that I already have the newest version 2.11.0-3+deb9u3

How can I update git to its latest release version?

Comment: The fact that git is already on 2.18.x doesn't mean that debian packagers have created newer packages for it. I just checked and my rpi also has git 2.11.0 and it runs fine. What is the error message you get when using git?

Answer (score 2):

Just because the software author has released a new version does not mean that it has made its way into the package manager's repositories yet.

You haven't said what software is throwing the error message, but I'm guessing it's not installed through the package manager. You should try installing it from there if you can.

If you cannot do that, you'll need to uninstall git. Once uninstalled, you can install it from the official website. Unfortunately, you'll likely have to install it from the source.